# Android: i'm already delete my data, but in room still exists some data

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have **Boolean booleanCheckAvailabilityData** to check availability data in my activity to  create add/remove favorite. then i create

`dataFavoriteMovieById = favoriteMovieViewModel.getAllFavoriteMovieById(idMovie);`

to get data by id. so i make conditional statement to check avaiability data then put the result to boolean and i use the boolean later to add or remove the favorite.

```
if (dataFavoriteMovieById == null) {
    booleanCheckAvailabilityData = false;
} else {
    booleanCheckAvailabilityData = true;
}
```

In the first run, it work. my **dataFavoriteMovieById** is null

[image: My First run]

But, after i add or remove favorite. it always always contains data (**RoomTrackingLiveData**).

[image: it contain RoomTrackingLiveData]

How can i solve this...

my code link : https://github.com/komangss/Submission-Menjadi-Android-Developer-Expert/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dicoding/submissionmade2_1/activity/DetailMovieActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with your app (thanks for providing a github link) and here are my results.

### Latest app version

Your latest implementation doesn't produce an NPE anymore since you use `getAllFavoriteMovieById` in a more consistent way. You no longer initialize a `LiveData` instance in `FavoriteMovieRepository` by yourself but delegate it to `Room` to do it for you. So, you won't get an NPE since `Room` will always create a list to return results. If there're no items, it will return an empty list. So, you can safely remove a `try/catch` here:

```
try {
    favoriteMovieViewModel.getAllFavoriteMovieById(idMovie).observe(this, new Observer<List<FavoriteMovie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<FavoriteMovie> favoriteMovies) {
            booleanCheckAvailabilityData = favoriteMovies.size() != 0;
        }
    });

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.d("ini bug nya", e.getMessage());
}
```

### Original app version

In addition to what @Paul Ost said about how `favoriteMovieViewModel` should be used properly (by listening to it, not using it directly), I will explain why you actually had an `NPE`.

In that version, you were running into a `NullPointerException` because you returned the `favoriteMovieById` LiveData before it was actually initialized in your `GetFavoriteMovieByIdAsyncTask`.

So, here what was happening in detail. First, once your `DetailMovieActivity` had been created, `favoriteMovieViewModel` called `getAllFavoriteMovieById()` as below:

#### DetailMovieActivity.java

```
...
favoriteMovieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FavoriteMovieViewModel.class);
dataFavoriteMovieById = favoriteMovieViewModel.getAllFavoriteMovieById(idMovie);
...
```

#### FavoriteMovieViewModel.java

`FavoriteMovieViewModel` instance, in turn, delegated the call to `FavoriteMovieRepository` instance as below:

```
public LiveData<List<FavoriteMovie>> getAllFavoriteMovieById(int idMovie) {
    return repository.getFavoriteMovieById(idMovie);
}
```

#### FavoriteMovieRepository.java

Finally, `getFavoriteMovieById` started a `GetFavoriteMovieByIdAsyncTask` and returned `favoriteMovieById`:

```
public LiveData<List<FavoriteMovie>> getFavoriteMovieById(int id_movie) {
    new GetFavoriteMovieByIdAsyncTask(favoriteMovieDao).execute(id_movie);
    return favoriteMovieById;
}
```

But that's **wrong**, since your **favoriteMovieById** was set to `null` by default, and so on the first run, you were always getting it.

Your AsyncTask was eventually setting a non-null value, but it was too late:

```
...
private static class GetFavoriteMovieByIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
  ... 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        FavoriteMovieRepository.favoriteMovieById = favoriteMovieDao.getFavoriteMovieById(integers[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your code - `getAllFavoriteMovieById` works as expected. The thing is - you are using `LiveData` as a return type of `getAllFavoriteMovieById` thus it returns not the value itself but a `LiveData` wrapper. But if you will try to observe this `LiveData` object you will(presumably since I haven't seen relevant code) receive null instead of favourite value. The only correct place to assign value to your `booleanCheckAvailabilityData` inside this observer(depending on your DAO code of course).

```
favouriteMovieViewModel.getAllFavoriteMovieById().observe(this, Observer { data ->
        if (data == null) {
            booleanCheckAvailabilityData = false;
        } else {
            booleanCheckAvailabilityData = true;
        }
})
```

Something like that(once again it depends on your DAO code and `getAllFavoriteMovieById` implementation)
Hope it helps.

Comment: im already try this, and unfortunately, it cause **NullPointerException** in my boolean. if i remove the try catch it will error :  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

In **ROOM** Try Deleting the *old TABLE* before inserting the new data. In that case the old data will be deleted as we are deleting the old data